# Area of a triangle and a trapezium

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

I have this triangle, of which I want to find an area. Is the given information enough? The length of the dotted line is 2, whereas, the length of `dotted + line` is sqrt(5). I can get the area of two small right angled triangle in top with 1/2 * base * height. But how do I get the area of lower trapezium?

Thanks a lot!

[image: triangle]

Comment: Note that the right triangle with hypotenuse labelled by the dotted line of length $\sqrt{5}$ is similar to the right triangles at the top of the diagram. Can you use this to deduce the height of the trapezium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use similar Triangles.
Using Pythagoras the side length of the smaller triangle is $\sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}$.

Knowing that the side length of the bigger triangle is the side length of the smaller triangle $+ \sqrt{5}$ we have that the side length of the larger triangle is $2\sqrt{5}$ so the ratio of smaller:bigger is 1:2.

Can you figure out the height of the bigger triangle now and consequently the area of the bigger triangle?